# How do I find tab chars in a word .docx using OpenXML?

Tags: c#, openxml

**Background:** I have a word .docx document that contains tab chars. I want to read each paragraph and substitute a single space. I need the space as a delimiter so I can parse out things like dates, names, etc.

**Problem:** Using paragraph.InnerText doesn't return the tab chars since they 
are a separate xml element. If I manually substitute spaces, my parsing routines work fine. However, using paragraph.InnerText the text returned is all scrunched up.

I have not been able to get the tab chars using run.InnerText either. I have searched for examples but have found none that solve the problem.

```
        using (WordprocessingDocument wordDocument = WordprocessingDocument.Open(filePath, false))
        {
            Body body = wordDocument.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body;

            foreach (var para in body.Elements<Paragraph>())
            {
                s = para.InnerText.ToString();      // Tab chars are stripped
                Console.WriteLine("Run: " + s);
            }
        }

        using (WordprocessingDocument wordDocument = WordprocessingDocument.Open(filePath, false))
            {
                Body body = wordDocument.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body;

                foreach (var para in body.Elements<Paragraph>())
                {
                    s = "";                 // Work string to build full line

                    foreach (var run in para.Elements<Run>())
                    {
                    //  If (This is a tab char)
                    //  { 
                    //     s = s + " ";     // Yes - Substitute a space 
                    //  }
                    //  else    // No - This assumes there are no other xml tags like "Proof Error"
                    //  {
                    //      s = s + run.InnerText.ToString();
                    //  }
                    }
                    Console.WriteLine("Run: " + s);
                }
```

Solved: I am able to find the tab chars and substitute spaces. Closing.

Answer (score 1):

I am using the .LocalName property of the run element. I can test for "tab".

```
                    foreach (var e in run.Elements())
                    {
                        if (e.LocalName == "tab")
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("    Element Tab: " + e.InnerText.ToString());
                            s = s + " ";
                        }
                        else if (e.LocalName == "t")
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("    Element Text: " + e.InnerText.ToString());
                            s = s + e.InnerText.ToString();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Drop Through RUN set: " + e.LocalName);
                        }
                    }
```

Comment: I don't have the authority to close this question. Would someone do this for me?